# 3n+1 Optimization Idea for Larger Integers

Tags: algorithm

I recently got into the book "Programming Challenges" by Skiena and Revilla and was somewhat surprised when I saw the solution to the 3n+1 problem, which was simply brute forced. Basically it's an algorithm that generates a list of numbers, dividing by 2 if even and multiplying by 3 and adding 1 if odd. This occurs until n=1 is reached, its base case. Now the trick is to find the maximum length of a list between integers i and j which in the problem ranges between 1 and 1,000,000 for both variables. So I was wondering how much more efficient (if so) a program would be with Dynamic Programming. Basically, the program would do one pass on the first number, i, find the total length, and then check each individual number within the array and store the associated lengths within a HashMap or other dictionary data type.

For Example: 
Let's say i = 22 and j = 23

For 22:

22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

This means that in the dictionary, with the structure  would store
(22,16) , (11,15) , (34,14) and so on... until (1,1)

Now for 23:

23 70 35 106 53 160 80 40 ...

Since 40 was hit, and it is in the dictionary
program would get the length of 23 to 80, which is 7, and add it to the length stored previously by 40 which is 9 resulting in total list length of 16. And of course the program would store lengths of 23, 70 , 35 etc... such that if the numbers were bigger it should compute faster.

So what are the opinions of approaching such a question in this manner?

Comment: Should be easy to try out and measure the performance difference no?

Comment: To clarify this: you're searching the number that requires most operations in the 3n+1 -algorithm and lies within a specific range? If so: I think I've already got a solution to that lying around somewhere, that is even faster than DP.

Comment: What is you question exactly?

Comment: I'm asking for the opinions of using my method to solve the problem described above. I'd like to know if more efficient solutions exist or if the efficiency is unnecessary. And @Paul I'm looking for what you said.

Comment: @Asymons I can't find the full-text solution. I'll build it from scratch again. Shouldn't take too long though.

Comment: Collatz hypothesis has been tested beyond 2^62. Would your method have a chance in hell?

Comment: (See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about asking for opinions (on Stack Overflow, _not_ all of Stack Exchange).) How much storage are you willing to invest? (Side note: for _o=e+1, (3o+1)/2 = 3(o//2)+2_)

Comment: @gnasher729 `have a chance in hell` to `find the maximum length of a [Collatz] list`?

Comment: @greybeard I think my question would be under a software algorithm, or related to that in some sort. And for all intensive purposes let's say maximum storage is 5MB.

Comment: `I think my question would be under a software algorithm` machine execution of an algorithm will require resources - not just time, but space, too. (You may want to store (and look up) lengths for odd values, only: for each factor of two/trailing zero in the binary representation of an even number, divide/shift (and add 1/the number of trailing zeroes to length …).)

Comment: Ah those some good suggestions to reduce storage time and not really increase the processing time significantly. Thanks @greybeard

Comment: You should really edit the question considerably to reflect what you're actually interested in. And I hope it's not "how to solve collatz faster" because that's a really broad area

Answer (score 0):

I tried both approaches and submitted them to [UVaOJ](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36), the brute force solution got runtime ~0.3s and the dp solution ~0.0s. It gets pretty slow when the range gets long (like over 1e7 elements).

I just used an array (memo) to be able to memorize the first 5 million (SIZE) values:

```
int cycleLength(long long n)
{
    if(n < 1) //overflow
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;

    if (n < SIZE && memo[n] != 0)
        return memo[n];

    int res = 1 + cycleLength(n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : 3 * n + 1);

    if (n < SIZE)
        memo[n] = res;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Sure you can share the code for people who may want to see it. I'm personally looking for opinions or if there are better methods to approaching said problem.